# rebuild image based of numpy arrays

Tags: numpy, opencv

I have this func that splits my initial img into arrays of 100x100

```
def blockshaped(arr, nrows, ncols):
    h, w = arr.shape
    return (arr.reshape(h//nrows, nrows, -1, ncols)
               .swapaxes(1,2)
               .reshape(-1, nrows, ncols))
```

Then this loop makes a new_img filled with arrays of zeros if enumerate == even, and block if is not

```
image = np.full((1000,2000),5)
blocks = blockshaped(image,100,100)

new_image = []
for i,block in enumerate(blocks):
    if i%2==0:
        new_image.append(np.zeros((100,100)))
    else:
        new_image.append(block)
```

Now I dont know how can I build a final image 1000x2000 filled with my new_image arrays.

Any idea???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just invert the steps you apply in `blockshaped()` to achieve this. Note that I renamed some of your variables to make the descriptions
shorter.

```py
import numpy as np

def blockshaped(arr, nrows, ncols):
    r, c = arr.shape                                       #    (r, c)
    return (arr.reshape(r//nrows, nrows, c//ncols, ncols)  # -> (r/n, n, c/m, m)
               .swapaxes(1, 2)                             # -> (r/n,  c/m, n, m)
               .reshape(-1, nrows, ncols))                 # -> (r/n * c/m, n, m)

r, c = 1000, 2000
n, m = 100, 100
image = np.full((r, c), 5)
blocks = blockshaped(image, nrows=n, ncols=m)

# Create new empty image and only fill in the even blocks
new_image = np.zeros((len(blocks), n, m))
new_image[::2] = blocks[::2]
# new_image[1::2] = np.full((n, m), 13)  # do something odd if you want

# reverse blockshaped                              #    (r/n * c/m, n, m)
new_image = (new_image.reshape(r//n, c//m, n,  m)  # -> (r/n,  c/m, n, m)
                      .swapaxes(1, 2)              # -> (r/n, n, c/m, m)
                      .reshape(image.shape))       # -> (r, c)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(new_image)
```

[image: Stripped Image of Blocks]

Comment: it works fine, but it was my fault I placed the example of ever or odd just to not complicate too much the code, in fact depending of a condition, the block can be zeros or not,
So I end with an arr that contain some original blocks and some zero blocks. And I am confused when I want to join all this blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You have created 200 number of 100 x 100 array using

```py
image = np.full((1000, 2000), 5)
blocks = block_shaped(image, 100, 100)
```

Then you want to fill the new array with the `block` values if counter is odd number.

```py
new_image = []
for i,block in enumerate(blocks):
    if i%2==0:
        new_image.append(np.zeros((100,100)))
    else:
        new_image.append(block)
```

- Instead of initializing `new_image` as an empty list, initialize as a numpy zeros array. The problem is what is the `shape` of the `new_image`?

The answer depends.

- If you want each row to be the blocks value, then you need to declare the size:

  - ```py
    new_image = np.zeros(shape=(2000, 10000))
    ```
  - Since each `block` is 100 x 100 = 10000 and the size of block is 200 x 100 x 100. We place each row `block` value, for instance `new_image[0, 10000] = block`.
  - ```py
    import numpy as np
    from PIL import Image


    def block_shaped(arr, n_rows, n_cols):
         h, w = arr.shape
         return (arr.reshape(h//n_rows, n_rows, -1, n_cols).swapaxes(1, 2).reshape(-1, n_rows, n_cols))


    image = np.full((1000, 2000), 5)
    blocks = block_shaped(image, 100, 100)

    new_image = np.zeros(shape=(2000, 10000), dtype=np.uint8)

    for i, block in enumerate(blocks):
         if i % 2 != 0:
             new_image[i, :] = block.flatten()

    new_image = Image.fromarray(new_image)
    new_image.show()
    ```
  - Result will be a blank image, but if you change `image = np.full((1000, 2000), 5)` to `image = np.full((1000, 2000), 155)`. Then the result will be:

    - [image]
    - Upper part becomes gray.
- If you want to set only `(100, 100)` parts of the image to the block for each odd i:

  - ```py
    import numpy as np
    from PIL import Image


    def block_shaped(arr, n_rows, n_cols):
        h, w = arr.shape
        return (arr.reshape(h//n_rows, n_rows, -1, n_cols).swapaxes(1, 2).reshape(-1, n_rows, n_cols))


    image = np.full((1000, 2000), 155)
    blocks = block_shaped(image, 100, 100)

    new_image = np.zeros(shape=(1000, 2000), dtype=np.uint8)

    for i, block in enumerate(blocks):
        if i % 2 != 0:
            new_image[i:100+i, i:100+i] = block

    new_image = Image.fromarray(new_image)
    new_image.show()
    ```
  - Result:

    - [image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think I have explain the problen wrong.

1.- I have an image (2000x1000)

2.- I split this img in sections of (100x100) total =200 blocks

3.- I loop all blocks and depending of a condition the block is left 
untouched, or is transformed into np.zeros

4,.- I end with a arr with some blocks untoched and some blocks with zeros.

5.- All this 4 steps are achived, but now I am confused about how can I rejoin all these blocks in a 2000x1000 img

Thanks for your time!